# I got this error on android adb command line

Tags: android, adb

When i was going to list permissions of android application, i got this error:

[image: This is image of error]

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aapt.exe is located under [SDK]\build-tools\23.0.1

Run it from that directory or add the directory to your local path.

Comment: I want to ask one more question.Why it doesnt navigate to right directory? I did it manually. Do you think there is any problem in my SDK?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your SDK.
Windows (or any other OS) doesn't know how to "navigate automatically", it just looks for the executable in the current directory and then in all directories configured in "PATH". To see the "PATH" directories, write "path" in command line. Check the following link to see how you update it - http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm